# iPhone App Audio/Sound Volume during Phone Calls (iPhone SDK)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, sdk

The question I have about the iOS SDK is this:  Can your iPhone app play sounds that can be intentionally heard by the person that is calling you (or that you called).  For example, if I want to "set the mood" for a phone call by playing nature sounds in the background during the call so that both myself and the other caller can hear the sounds, is this possible.

I know that as the phone call comes in, the app sound goes into interruption mode or background, but can I then manipulate (e.g. increase) the volume of the background sound from the app (even though there was an interruption by the phone call) such that it can be heard by both parties during the call.

Any advice on this would be helpful.